# Access encrypted Ubuntu disk on macOS

Tags: unix, encryption

I'm trying to access a disk, from macOS, that has an Ubuntu installation on it. I was able to mount the disk with Paragon ExtFS tool but I don't know how to go about the encryption part. I do have the passphrase.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no native method to access an encrypted Linux volume on macOS.

A technique that may work for you is downloading [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) (a free and open source virtual machine program), installing a Linux distribution in a VM, setting the host (macOS)'s `/dev` directory as shared to the VM, and then try to mount the disk on the virtual machine, through the shared `/dev` file. The likelihood of this working is not great, but it might work. Can't hurt to try.